# Cannot connect to headless virtualbox-ose: rfbProcessClientProtocolVersion: not a valid RFB client

Tags: virtualbox, rdp

I've set up a headless virtualbox-ose on a FreeBSD-10 server. Everything looks normal, but I cannot connect to it using RDP. On a Mac running Yosemite, no matter which client I've tried, the server complains that it is not a valid RFB client:

```
$ VBoxHeadless --startvm testvm
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.3.16_OSE
(C) 2008-2014 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

07/11/2014 00:15:42 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 3389
07/11/2014 00:15:42 Listening for VNC connections on TCP6 port 5900
VRDE server is listening on port 5901.
07/11/2014 00:16:28   other clients:
07/11/2014 00:16:28 rfbProcessClientProtocolVersion: not a valid RFB client: 
07/11/2014 00:16:28 Client 192.168.1.2 gone
07/11/2014 00:16:28 Statistics             events    Transmit/ RawEquiv ( saved)
07/11/2014 00:16:28  TOTALS              :      0 |         0/        0 (  0.0%)
07/11/2014 00:16:28 Statistics             events    Received/ RawEquiv ( saved)
07/11/2014 00:16:28  TOTALS              :      0 |         0/        0 (  0.0%)
```

I've tried rdesktop from a fresh MacPorts, and also Microsoft Remote Desktop, fresh from AppStore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that even though the documentation claims it is RDP, it is not. At least not the OSE version. It is plain VNC, even for VirtualBox 4.3.

Connecting with a VNC client, like vnc from macports, seems to do the job.